# C# Property Delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates

In my other methods I could do something like this,

```
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<T>(Add), item);
        }
    }
```

But how do I invoke a property for a situation like this?

```
    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            ...
        }
        set
        {
            if (dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                ...
            }
            else
            {
                dispatcher.Invoke(???, value, index); // <-- problem is here
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Edit:** The following paragraph no longer applies, as the OP's question has since been edited.*

<strike>First off, your second code seems **logically incorrect**: You apparently want to call the setter, but while you provide a value for `index`, you don't provide the actual `value` (i.e. `item`). I'll return to that issue in a second.</strike>

---

You could **wrap an anonymous delegate or lambda function around the property setter**, e.g. (using an anonymous delegate) to make it invokable:

```
dispatcher.Invoke(
    new Action<T>(  delegate (T item) { this[index] = item; }  ),
    item );
```

or (using a lambda function available since C# language version 3):

```
dispatcher.Invoke(
    new Action<T>(  (T item) => { this[index] = item; }  ),
    item );
```

**Note:** You create an anonymous delegate or lambda function that accepts one argument (`item`). The other required argument (`index`) is taken from the "outer" context. (The term *closure* comes to mind.) I see this as the only way how you would not have to change your `dispatcher` to a delegate type that is sometimes invoked with two arguments instead of one.

If this however is not an issue, the `Invoke` code could change to e.g.:

```
dispatcher.Invoke(
    new Action<int,T>(  (int index, T item) => { this[index] = item; }  ),
    index, item );
```

Comment: Oops, forgot to pass `value` back. I'll try this tomorrow. I *thought* I could do something like this, but I couldn't remember the proper syntax.

Comment: Why do you pass the item but not the index to the delegate? If it's not necessary to pass index, then it shouldn't be necessary to pass the item either? `dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { this[index] = value; }));`

Comment: From looking at the code you posted in your question, I assumed that `dispatcher.Invoke` required an `Action<T>` (ie. a delegate with only one parameter). However, if you can pass two arguments, then of course you could just as well pass `index` directly to the delegate, too. Choose what works best in your case!

Comment: @Mark: added a third code example with a two-parameter lambda function.